# Finding a substring in Python RegEx considering pairing of LaTeX brakets and ignoring eol

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need to find the contents of certain LaTeX macros in Python in LaTeX articles, taking into account the pairing of brakets, but without taking into account single eol characters. For example,

```
\title[Synthesis of knowledge: problems and methods\ldots]
{Synthesis of knowledge: problems and methods when building 
models of intelligent systems}

\abstract{Problems of using {\it regular structures} of memory 
$\Sigma =\{\Sigma(z)  \vert z\in M\}$ 
and $\tilde{\Sigma}  =  \{\tilde{\Sigma}(z)   \vert z\in R\}$ 
to model the processes of synthesis of knowledge structures 
with the help of knowledge processing operations from special 
classes of such operations are considered. These structures 
define the formats of the memory subdomains used.

Area formats match domain element structures
(domains of definition and meaning of operations)...}

\keywords{knowledge structures, ...}
```

Briefly about the syntax. Macros in LaTeX start with a `\` then, after the name of the macro, may or may not be followed by an optional parameter in a pair of square brackets `[]`, and the required parameter in a pair of curly braces `{}`. Curly braces are also used to create so-called groups (something like a scope restriction). If you need to display the curly brace itself, write, for example, `\{` in the text. LaTeX does not take into account multiple spaces (they turn into a single space) and single newlines (they also turn into a single space later). A new paragraph is indicated by two newlines. This is a simplified description of the LaTeX syntax, but in my case it is completely correct.

I need a function that returns the content of the required argument of `word` macro from a previously read `file` like this

```
def tag(file, word): # file - content of LaTeX fileа, word - name of macro
    regex = re.compile(r'\\' + word + '\[?.*?\]?\{(.*)\}', re.MULTILINE)
    return regex.findall(file)[0]
```

This function works well only if the content of the desired command is one line (and which is logical), because when using `re.DOTALL` it can be seen that it is too greedy. But I need it to be neither too greedy nor too lazy and must take into account the pairing of curly braces, the nesting of which can be quite large, and also ignore single eol characters (just replace them with spaces), but at the same time two translation characters strings would be converted to a single line terminator.

That is, as a result, I need the `tag(file, 'abstract')` to return this

```
Problems of using {\it regular structures} of memory $\Sigma =\{\Sigma(z) \vert z\in M\}$ and $\tilde{\Sigma} = \{\tilde{\Sigma}(z) \vert z\in R\}$ to model the processes of synthesis of knowledge structures with the help of knowledge processing operations from special classes of such operations are considered. These structures define the formats of the memory subdomains used.
Area formats match domain element structures (domains of definition and meaning of operations)...
```

I would be grateful for advice on constructing a correct regular expression.

Comment: Nested syntax is not regular. While some regular expression library are capable of parsing nested structures, the result is fragile, unmaintainable, and usually inefficient. Regular expressions are great for what they are good at, but as soon as you hit a nested syntax, the alarms should start to sound. At that point you need a parser, not a regex library.

Comment: @rici I got it, thanks. Is it easier to write a recursive function for parsing or use ready-made Python's packages?

Comment: There was is at least one Python package; I've never tried it but it's probably worth checking out at least: https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/